# Heroku endpoint ssl: is it possible to have https and http on the same domain?

Tags: ssl, heroku

Does the new heroku endpoint ssl support having both http and https on a single domain?

I would like to serve some pages via http://www.mydomain.com and also serve profile pages via https://www.mydomain.com/profile.

With the old ssl I needed to create secure.mydomain.com for https but I would rather not do this if possible.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.  All you're adding with endpoint SSL is a entry point in front of your actual app that supports SSL.  HTTP can still travel through this just fine, but obviously won't be secure.